# Rvalue (Reference) in C++11

Tags: c++11

There are quite many threads about rvalue (reference).

But I haven't found the answer to my following question:

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move, std::move() takes a rvalue reference as the parameter.

According to the graph in C++11 Standard https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKlod.png, a lvalue won't be rvalue.

Common usage of std::move():

```
Foo f;
std::deque<Foo> fq;
fq.push_back(std::move(f));
```

f is a lvalue because it is an object according to C++11 standard:

> An lvalue (so-called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function or an object. [Example: If E is an expression of pointer type, then *E is an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which E points. As another example, the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue.]

Then, in theory, std::move(f) should give me an compile error, but it doesn't.  I am sure that I miss something...

Any input is welcome.

Comment: Actually, the fuss with std::move is redundant. std::vector has emplace_back for this purpose

Comment: Actually, `std::move` does not take an rvalue-reference, but a forwarding-reference (aka universal reference), which means it can be either an lvalue and and rvalue reference.

Comment: @remyabel what's the "collapsing rule"?

Comment: @Deduplicator so T&& is forwarding-reference/universal reference?  Then, how do we specify rvalue reference as a type of a parameter?

Comment: @Hei It is only in a context where `T` is deduced, like the prototype of the `std::move`-template. In that case, if you really want to restrict to rvalue-references, use SFINAE or `static_assert` and type-traits.

Comment: @Hei Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: An rvalue reference is not an rvalue. It's actually an lvalue. What std::move does is basically a static_cast to an rvalue, so that it will bind to a rvalue reference.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter to `std::move` is type `T &&`, where `T` is deduced. This is called a *forwarding reference*.*

The trick is that a declaration `T & &&` generated by a template is equivalent to `T &`. When you pass an lvalue `int` to `move`, then the type `T` in `T &&` is deduced `T = int &` and the entire parameter is type `int & && = int &`. This is called *reference collapsing*.

As you observed, it is illegal to pass an lvalue to an rvalue parameter, but reference collapsing prevents this from happening.

The practice of defining a function which works with lvalue or rvalue references, by declaring such a reference, is called *perfect forwarding*, hence the reference is a forwading reference. The argument is "forwarded" because it behaves the same inside the function as it did in the function call, provided [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is used to restore rvalue-ness.

* The term *universal reference* is being [deprecated](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Deduplicator, `&&` only means universal reference in cases where `T` is a deduced type. Scott Meyer's [comprehensive blog post on Universal References](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) provides an easy to remember quote:

> If a variable or parameter is declared to have type T&& for some
>   deduced type T, that variable or parameter is a universal reference.

As well as a code sample:

```
Widget&& var1 = someWidget; // here, “&&” means rvalue reference

auto&& var2 = var1; // here, “&&” does not mean rvalue reference

template<typename T>
void f(std::vector<T>&& param); // here, “&&” means rvalue reference

template<typename T>
void f(T&& param);               // here, “&&”does not mean rvalue reference
```

As covered by [Thomas Becker](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html), `std::move` accepts a universal reference to take advantage of perfect forwarding.

Even though push_back takes a `T&&`, this is not a universal reference, as explained by Scott Meyers. `T` is already deduced in this instance:

```
template <class T>
void vector<T>::push_back(T&& x);
```

so the parameter actually becomes an rvalue reference. To give a practical example, consider a template class that doesn't have an overload that takes an lvalue reference:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    void push_back(T&& t);
};

template <typename T>
void Test<T>::push_back(T&& t) { std::cout << "rvalue overload.\n"; }

int main()
{
    Test<int> t;
    t.push_back(42);
    int i = 50;
    t.push_back(i);
    return 0;
}
```

`t.push_back(i)` would give an error.

Answer (score 0):

"Rvalue reference" doesn't mean a reference that is an rvalue. It's just a description of the type (`T&&` rather than `T&`). It's confusingly named in that regard. The value category of `f` is indeed *lvalue* and that's fine.